# Collective term for shaking device and using accelerometer of a device

Tags: terminology

Does anyone know what the collective term for shaking a device to achieve something or using the accelerometer of a device to do something is? Is it haptic technology?

Comment: hap·tic/ˈhaptik/
Adjective: Of or relating to the sense of touch.

Comment: Haptics usually refers to a device that responds to user interaction with tactile feedback - like the rumble pack in game controllers or vibrator in a phone or the haptic mechanism in the screen of some of the fancier BlackBerrys. (Blackberries?)

Answer (score 4):

I would say semantically [Kinetic](http://ki%C2%B7net%C2%B7ic%20adjective%E2%80%83/k%C9%99%CB%88netik/%E2%80%83%20%20Of,%20relating%20to,%20or%20resulting%20from%20motion%20%20%28of%20a%20work%20of%20art%29%20Depending%20on%20movement%20for%20its%20effect) would be a better term than [Haptic](http://www.google.com/search?q=define:haptic#hl=en&q=haptic&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=RRx5TveSKsW2tgfv_OH1Dw&ved=0CC4QkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=b87834403f6d633d&biw=1203&bih=885).

**ki·net·ic**
*adjective /kəˈnetik/*

> Of, relating to, or resulting from motion
>
> (of a work of art) Depending on movement for its effect

For semantics questions like this [english.stackexchange.com](https://english.stackexchange.com/) is very valuable.

The iPhone 4 for example has 2 accelerometers and 1 gyroscope, all of which rely on motion ( kinetic action ) and nothing to do with touch ( haptic ).

Comment: +1: seems much more correct, another +1 for link to the English Q&A ...

Comment: So would you say if someone shook their phone to perform an action they were using Kinetic Technology?

Comment: @Jonas Nielsen: <pedantic>I would say they were using the accelerometer. </pedantic>

Comment: @Tux-D the iPhone 4 has more motion sensors than just the accelerometers, it also has a gyroscope which is kinetic motion input as well.